# How does the Roost Smart Battery connect?

Tags: smart-home, roost

I've been reading about the Roost Smart Battery.  Essentially, it's a battery you can install in your smoke detector which is supposed to notify you on your phone if your smoke detector goes off.  It also gives you the capability of silencing your smoke detector from your phone.

According to [The Wire Cutter](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-smart-smoke-alarm/):

> ...Roost will automatically notify someone else about the alarm in your home when it’s triggered, without giving that person control over all your other smart-home devices (as is the case with Nest’s version of this feature). But unlike the [Nest] Protect, the Smart Battery doesn’t give you voice alerts, wireless interconnectivity, integrations with smart-home devices, or self-testing sensors [...]

According to my understand (maybe flawed) of the word interconnectivity, it means something along the lines of this definition from Wikipedia:

> Interconnectivity refers to the state or quality of being connected together, or to the potential to connect in an easy and effective way

If the Smart Battery is not in the state of being connected together with your phone, how would they communicate?  There is obviously a flawed premise.  I assume the flawed premise is my definition of the term interconnectivity.  What do they mean by saying that the Roost Smart Battery does not give wireless interconnectivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context, I believe it is referring to interconnectivity **with other alarms in the house**. From earlier in the article:

> Most important, an alarm should connect wirelessly with other alarms in the home, or come in a hardwired version that you can wire to other alarms, so that when one alarm senses danger all alarms in the house will sound. This is a crucial safety feature that can save you precious seconds in evacuating your home. Also, many states now require interconnected alarms for new construction, so if you do a significant remodel in your home, you don’t want to end up having to buy a different brand of alarm for the new area (most brands don’t play well with one another when it comes to interconnected alerts).

The author of that article seems to use  *interconnected* to refer to the alarms connecting together so that they all sound together in case of a fire. The Roost Smart Battery does not do this, because it just works by listening to detect your alarm going off with a piezoelectric sensor, [according to TechHive](http://www.techhive.com/article/3004024/home-tech/roost-smart-battery-review-this-is-the-best-smoke-alarm-battery-you-can-buy.html):

> The detector relies on the high-pitched sound of the alarm to deform a piezo-electric sensor to trigger its own alarm. I intentionally installed the battery in the smoke detector in my master bedroom because its siren is defective—it makes more of a growl than a high-pitched squeal. But the Roost still went into an alarm state, perhaps after picking up the noise of the detector in the hallway.

Your smoke alarm is still 'dumb' and can't share its state with other alarms, and the smart battery has no way of causing your alarm to trigger, either.

The [Roost Smart Battery](http://getroost.com/index) is **definitely** connecting wirelessly with your phone, though. The title of their website is *"Roost Wi-Fi battery for smoke and CO alarms"*, so it's plainly obvious that the device does connect via Wi-Fi to your phone.